# Gmail is crashing Android 4.4.2 while sending email using email Intent

Tags: android, email, android-intent

I am using following code for sending attachment using email Intent. Gmail is crashing Android 4.4.2 while sending email. The native email client sends email perfectly with PDF attachment and it is not crashing. Is anything wrong here?

```
File rootPath = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "MyApp");


            if(!rootPath.exists()) {
                rootPath.mkdirs();
            }

        File f = new File(rootPath, "Report.pdf");
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(f);
        document.writeTo(fos);
        document.close();
        fos.close();

        final Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        Uri uri = Uri.parse("file://" + rootPath + "/"+ "Report.pdf");

        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Report");
        emailIntent.putExtra(
                Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,
                Html.fromHtml("Report"));
        emailIntent.setType("application/pdf");
        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);

        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send email using: "));
```

Following is the stack trace of gmail client.
[image]

Comment: I would strongly recommend using `Uri.fromFile()` rather than `Uri.parse()`. And, AFAIK, only either `EXTRA_TEXT` *or* `EXTRA_STREAM` is supported, not both on the same `ACTION_SEND` `Intent`. And, since your `EXTRA_TEXT` is not actually HTML, don't use `Html.fromHtml()`.

Comment: Thanks. Made those changes. Gmail is still crashing. the native email client works.

Comment: Post the stack trace, and perhaps that will give somebody some clues.

Comment: Added gmail stack trace.

Comment: It's trying to use a `ContentResolver` for some reason.